# setting cookies using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie using asp.net webpages (Webmatrix) and I have been given this c# code to read a cookie and set a cookie. I am not sure how to apply it to set a cookie though. For example, I am looking to set a cookie called islogged and give it a value of yes.

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["myCookie"].Value;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case:

```
// Set the value in a response
Response.Cookies["islogged"].Value = "true";

// After a post back read the value from the request
Request.Cookies["islogged"].Value;
```

To learn more, you can take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks - that makes perfect sense - much more simple to understand than MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("islogged", "true"));
```